# For free fields, is there a one-to-one correspondence between probability distribution of classical field configurations, and states?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, probability, classical-field-theory, quantum-states

If I'm given the field operator of free fields (for example $\phi(x)$) as a function of space time, and a state (for example $\langle 0 | $, I can calculate the expectation value for every point in space time $\langle \phi(x) \rangle$.

So now my question is: Is it possible to not only calculate the expectation value, but also any other statistical moment, and retrieve a probability distribution for a classical value / field $\phi(x)$? If so, will it be a distinct probability distribution for values of $\phi(x)$, or will it be a "probability functional" $\rho[\phi]$?

Calculating $\langle \phi (x) \rangle$ and higher momenta here was just an example for a way I proposed to get the probability density. Obtaining the probability will probably also involve the operator $\phi^\dagger$ in that example.

I assume the latter, because there surely can be correlations.

If there is this correspondence between the state $|a\rangle$ and the said probability distribution, does it also work the other way around? And will this correspondence only work for free scalar fields, or will it also hold for vector-fields and Dirac fields?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in general, a field operator will always give you
$$\langle n|\phi(x)|n\rangle=0 , $$
for a Fock state with occupation number $n$. The reason is that the field operator is linear in ladder operators and the single ladder operator would make the bra and ket of the Fock state mutually orthogonal. For instance
$$\langle n|\hat{a}^{\dagger}|n\rangle=\langle n|n+1\rangle \sqrt{n+1} =0 . $$

Secondly, the field operator does not represent a state. It, together with its adjoint, provide the tools to formulate observations on a state. Take for instance, the number operator
$$ \hat{n} = \phi^{\dagger}\phi . $$
When the Fock states are applied to it as in
$$\langle n|\phi^{\dagger}\phi|n\rangle=\text{tr}\{\hat{n}\hat{\rho}\}=n , $$
the result, tells us something about the Fock state, represented as a density operator $\hat{\rho}=|n\rangle\langle n|$, and not so much about the field operators. Therefore, the various correlation measurements that we can apply to a state using the field operators will provide statistical properties for that state.

With that understanding, we can now ask whether the correlation measurement will correspond to a probability density as it does in the case of classical physics. The answer is no. To see this, one can consider for example the [Wigner function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution) of (in this case) the Fock states. It represents a *quasi* probability distribution on phase space, because the function is negative at some locations in phase space. Its Fourier transform is a [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) from which you can calculate all the moments. Therefore, there is a direct link between the correlations that you can measure for a given quantum state and its Wigner function. Yet, for a quantum state, like a Fock state, such a Wigner function cannot be associated with a probability distribution as one would expect for a classical state.

Comment: I edited the question, as I meant "fock state" only as a word to describe a state from a fock space. 
Still - even for those states with definite particle number n, we can for example calculate expectation values involving $\phi^\dagger$, $\phi$, and correlations. 

Thus I don't yet see that the general answer to my question should be "no", just because VEVs are always zero.

Comment: Would this apply also to field configurations? Namely, that from a state of a free quantum field theory, I can only retrieve a quasi-probability distribution of all possible field configurations?

Comment: There are states that are more classical. They will give distributions that can be represented as true probability distributions. In that case, it may be more useful to use the Glauber-Sudarshan P distributions instead of Wigner functions. The P distribution of a thermal state, for example, is a true probability distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the question completely, but here is a try at an answer:

In general, if you have all the moments of a statistical distribution $\rho(x)$ then you can construct it (simply by relating them to the FT of the distribution). Naively, this will mean that if you have all the moments at every point $\Phi^{(n)}(x) = \langle\psi| \phi^n(x)| \psi\rangle$ then you will be able to construct the state $|\psi\rangle$. But that is not the case in the quantum case, as we may attach *local* phase to the field configuration at each point, and the moments will remain identical, while the physical content will change.

Comment: If I get you right, this means that I don't need a distrubtion for $\phi(x)$ at each point, but instead I need a distribution $\rho[\phi]$ that assigns a probability density to each possible field configuration. Your argument doesn't apply in that case, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: your question is not very clear and i don't understand what you mean by "a distribution that assigns a probability density to each field configuration". you mean something like a density matrix? is $\phi(x)$ known or not? when you write $\rho[\phi(x)]$ are you referring to probablity distribution for expectation value $\langle \phi(x) \rangle$ or for the probability distribution of the entire wave-function encoded in the state $|\psi\rangle$?

Comment: When I write $\rho[\phi]$, I mean the probability distribution for the entire field function encoded in state $|\psi\rangle$

Comment: i'm sorry i still don't understand. when i sample from this distribution do i sample a state $|\psi\rangle$? an entire configuration (which is the same thing as sampling a state $|\psi\rangle$? or an expectation value at some point / all points? if it is the former, than the analog to $\rho[\phi]$ is the density matrix, and not a pure state $|\psi\rangle$, as they pertain to different things completely

Comment: I'm talking about a classical field $\phi(x)$ (which is a function of x). Any function of x represents such a classical field configuration (2 fields  $\phi$ and $\phi'$ which differ only in some places x are still two different fields). I can assign a probability-density to any of those field configurations $\rho[\phi]$. I'm asking if this probability-density can be retrieved from given state $|\psi \rangle$ in a free quantum field theory.